# server socket in a new thread

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, pthreads

I want to create a server socket but  don't want to block my main application by the "accept call". So I will create a socket in main application. using pthread mechanism I created a new thread in which I will use "accept call" in it. After creating socket in main application, I called "pthread join". Now when this thread executes, "accept call" is again blocking the main application. I checked using gdb. How I should go about this problem?

Comment: "The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates." - which means it will block the main thread because the new thread will still be listening to any new calls. For more detailed info go here: [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html)

Comment: So, without calling pthread_join() works for me?

Comment: Protip - don't call pthread_join unless you have no choice.  In your case, an accept loop, there is no need to, ever.

Comment: Then what scenarios pthread join() is used?. If the main thread is suspended. Its like calling one function after another. We no need of threads at all I feel.

Comment: @SnehaDolly if you are going to wait for them, one-by-one no, there is no point.  If your thread has the same lifetime as the process, eg. your accept() loop, or pooled threads,  join is not required and, if possible, should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make the main server socket descriptor as non-blocking and use select system call. When select returns and the main socket descriptor is having data, create a new thread to handle the newly accepted connection. This way you can achieve parallelism, The new connection, which was created will have it's own context and will be scheduled as and when possible even though while accept() waits for a connection.

Comment: There is no point in using select() in the accept() loop.  Nothing is gained, and you have to make an extra system call.  You understand that select() is a blocking call, yes?

Comment: @Naresh. As said by Martin James, select call is blocking. Therefore the main application will block. I have a scenario where main application should not block. And I don't know when client ll come n connect.